# Powershell Date Parsing for Sharepoint Set-SPOListItem Update

Tags: powershell, .net

I am trying to parse a CSV file in Powershell for a bulk file and metadata upload to SharePoint Online and am failing on the date fields.
 The incoming date format is '2007/12/24', the expected SPO outgoing date format is '2007-12-24T00:00:00Z'.

I tried the following:

```
$Metadata.add(  "CreatedDate",   ([datetime]::ParseExact($_."Date Created","yyyy/MM/dd",$null)).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))
```

Also Tried this:

```
$Metadata.add(  "CreatedDate",   (Get-Date ([datetime]::ParseExact($_."Date Created","yyyy/MM/dd",$null)) -Format d).ToString())
```

And this:

```
$Metadata.add(  "CreatedDate",   (Get-Date ([datetime]::ParseExact($_."Date Created","yyyy/MM/dd",$null)) -Format u).ToString())
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Set-SPOListItem : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
At C:\Users\thebear\Desktop\SODA\SODABulkUploadTest3.ps1:108 char:5
Set-SPOListItem -List SEDA -Identity $($Upload.ListItemAllFields. ...
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are 4 date fields in the CSV file, and if any of them are empty, all of the examples above fail!
I added if ([bool]$_."Date Created") {...} to each of the date lines to resolve this case.